# Layer is refreshed after an ajax request with openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, ext-js

I can't understand why my vector is empy after this ajax request :

```
function loadKMLTMINT(terminalcode) {
    MapPanel.el.mask();
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'php/GetKMLTM.php',
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
            terminalcode: terminalcode
        },
        success: function (r) {
             if (r.responseText.length > 0) {
                var data_tmp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(r.responseText));
                vector_term.parseFeatures(data_tmp, new ol.parser.GeoJSON(), ol.proj.get("EPSG:3857"));
                var first = true, precExtent = [];
                for (var vec in vector_term.featureCache_.idLookup_) {
                    if (vector_term.featureCache_.idLookup_[vec].values_.Intermodal == 'Y' && vector_term.featureCache_.idLookup_[vec].values_.NAME.substring(0, 5) === terminalcode.substring(3, 8)){
                        if (first) {
                            first = false;
                            precExtent = vector_term.featureCache_.idLookup_[vec].values_.geometry.rings_[0].bounds_;
                        } else {
                            ol.extent.extend(precExtent, vector_term.featureCache_.idLookup_[vec].values_.geometry.rings_[0].bounds_);
                        }
                    }
                }
                olmap.getView().fitExtent(precExtent, olmap.getSize());
            } 
            MapPanel.el.unmask();
        }
    }); 
}
```

I'm calling this function many time, in order to add some values to the layer vector_term. With the debugging I can see that my vector_term is full when I call the function, but when it reaches the `success: function(r)` it becomes empty !

Do you know if I'm doing something wrong?

Should I use `addFeatures` instead of `parseFeatures`?

---

vector_term definition

```
var vector_term = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        parser: new ol.parser.GeoJSON()
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        rules: [
            new ol.style.Rule({
                filter : 'geometryType("polygon")',
                symbolizers: [
                    new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: ol.expr.parse('color'),
                        opacity: 0.4
                    }),
                    new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: ol.expr.parse('color'),
                        opacity: 0.8
                    }),
                    new ol.style.Text({
                        color: '#0A3ABF', //'#165EF0',
                        text: ol.expr.parse('NAME'),
                        fontFamily: 'Arial',
                        fontSize: 14,
                        zIndex: 7
                    })
                ]
            })
        ]
    })
});
```

Comment: What is the CLASS of vector_term? You have not added features to vector layer.

Comment: @neogeomat for me I add features with parseFeatures. I edit to show you vector_term

Comment: Since vector_term is a local variable; Have you checked whether it is available inside the success function(r)?

Comment: @neogeomat Yes vector_term is not undefined, the feature is just removed. The fact is vector_term features still exist until it comes on the success line, and my php is not modifying the vector or anything else

Comment: define vector term as global variable or pass it as argument in loadKMLTMINT function.

Comment: Thanks for the good idea, don't know if it's the parameter but even by not touching it it's working now... Don't know why, but thanks for time lef !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either define `vector_term` as global variable or pass it as argument in `loadKMLTMINT` function. To pass as parameter the function definition should be

```
function loadKMLTMINT(terminalcode,vector_term) {
```